# Display something on the screen everytime action made

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a problem not sure how to solve this. Hmm I am developing a game, a multi touch game, I already can make everything working fine, except a small issue that I want to show messages on the playing screen, each time the player makes actions. like his finger moves right the message says : "this finger moving right" nicely at the bottom of the screen, then if the finger move left, then it says the his finger moves left... something like that, can anyone show me how. I am using Cocos2D , it shall be much easier in Cocoa.

Thanks a alot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to be more specific with your question, but for now, here's a general answer:

[Handling touch events on the iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW15) and [Handling touch ("trackpad") events on the Mac](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW1).

You'll receive and process the events per the above, then you'll display the results somehow. For testing, you'll probably just want to log the results to the console. For the final version, you might have a label or even a custom view that draws the "instruction" in some fancier way. If the latter is the case, you'll want to read up on custom views and drawing for whichever platform you're using (or both).